# Implementing Bubble Sort in the custom LinkedList. Sorting more than 4 elements triggers a NullPointerException

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

This code below is an implementation of linked List data structure.

I'm using *Bubble sorting* to sort its elements.

When I'm entering more than `4` elements, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

*My code:*

```
public class Main {
    
    Node head = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number;
    
    void insert() {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of data. ");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the data.");
            int data = sc.nextInt();
            Node n = new Node(data);
            if (head == null) {
                head = n;
            } else {
                n.next = head;
                head = n;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void sorting() {
        Node temp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < number - 2; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < number - i - 2; k++) {
                while (temp.data > temp.next.data) {
                    int data1 = temp.data;
                    temp.data = temp.next.data;
                    temp.next.data = data1;
                    System.out.println(2);
                }
                System.out.println(1);
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void print() {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    
    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        
        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main n = new Main();
        n.insert();
        n.sorting();
        n.print();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I would advise you to take time and trace your code first

Comment: Your code doesn't even work for some inputs consisting of three elements like ```1 2 3```.  Are you sure you've understood how BubbleSort works?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just translate bubble-sort on `array` into a `linked-list`. The reason behind this is, that in the array, the inner-loop will reinitialize onto "0" for each iteration of the outer loop variable.

example -

```
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){ }
}
```

Here inner-loop variable `"j"` will be reinitialized to 0 and start comparing values from it, each time the outer loop `"i"` increments.

But the same is not true, in your code. The temporary variable of `head` node, `temp` increments forever and never reinitialized to the start of the head again. In a simpler way, it swaps values only one time for each item.

To overcome this, you need to reinitialize your `temp` each time your outer loop iterates one.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29869792) out.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your solution is a faulty implementation of `sort()` method.

You've declared variable `temp` in the wrong place (the code below). It should be reassigned with the reference to *head-node* at every step of the iteration of the outer `for` loop. But instead because of the line in the inner loop:

```
temp = temp.next;
```

variable `temp` at the end of the first iteration it points at the `next` node of the very last *node* in the *list* (which would be `null`, there's no *next node* that comes after the *last node*). And at the second step of iteration of the outer loop, `temp.next` produces a `NullPointerException` because `temp` is `null`. Hence, we should reinitialize it at the beginning of each iteration step.

You also don't need a `while` loop nested inside the inner `for` loop. The process of swapping the value of the list elements should happen inside the inner loop.

*Sidenote: try to give your variables, as well as methods and classes meaningful names, for example `size` is more suitable than `number`.*

Termination conditions `< number - 2` in both `for` loops are incorrect. Instead, you need to iterate through the list until the node which is **before** the very last node (i.e. until the *list size* - `1`) because you're checking the value of the *next node* inside the inner loop.

That's how your code can be fixed:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    private ConnectedComponents.SinglyLinkedList.Node head = null;
    private int size;
    
    public void insert() {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Nodes to insert: ");
        
        int newNodes = sc.nextInt(); // don't override the size of the list
        size += newNodes;            // add the number of new nodes to the current size
        
        for (int i = 0; i < newNodes; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the data for the Node " + i + " :");
            int data = sc.nextInt();
            ConnectedComponents.SinglyLinkedList.Node newNode = new ConnectedComponents.SinglyLinkedList.Node(data);
            if (head != null) {
                newNode.next = head;
            }
            head = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    public void sorting() {
//            Node temp = head; <- that's a WRONG place to declare this variable, see variables in the loop
        
        if (size <= 1) return;    // there's no need to sort list of size 0 or 1, hence returning from the method
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ConnectedComponents.SinglyLinkedList.Node cur = head;      // every iteration step of the outer loop should start with reassigning these variables
            
            for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++) {
                
                if (cur.data > cur.next.data) {
                    int temp = cur.data;
                    cur.data = cur.next.data;
                    cur.next.data = temp;
                }
                
                cur = cur.next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    void print() {
        ConnectedComponents.SinglyLinkedList.Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    
    public class Node {
        private int data;
        private ConnectedComponents.SinglyLinkedList.Node next;
        
        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

*Class Main:*

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedList list = new SinglyLinkedList();
        list.insert();
        list.sorting();
        list.print();
    }
}
```